# What is the different between a Controller and Plug in Elixir Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Coming from Node.js/Express background, I see that `plug` is basically an equivalent to middleware in Phoenix framework. After reading about `Controllers`, I notices that `Controller` is also a `Plug` which themselves can contain one or more plugs.

I am confused exactly about the usage of Plug and Controller.

- Plug enables composition. How is that different from normal function composition
- What is the difference between a Plug and a Controller? When to use what since I can do early exit from Plug as well?
- Finally, controller has `Actions`. These actions again have same signature as that of a **function based Plug**. So how an action is different from a Plug?

Comment: _Controller_ is a _Phoenix’_ name for “Plug on steroids.”

Answer (score 2):

A plug takes in a connection and returns it modified. So yes a controller is also a plug; actions are also plugs. I have the same analogy as you, I take function plugs and module plug as middlewares in other frameworks.

You should use a plug if "every" time a request is sent to your server, you need to pre-process to verify some conditions/things or set some variables and take action before the controller is called. e.g Authentication, i18n... I could say that most time these things are set on cookies, session, http-headers... For example in authentication, if the user is not having a session or a token, you can `halt` the connection before it even arriving in the controller, in the other case where it's set(session, or token), you can fetch the user from the database and set it in the connection `assigns`, which will be available during the the request live cycle.

A controller should be used to handle a particular set of actions generally related to a particular resource. Everything needed should be loaded with plugs before the controller is called ideally. If you have to show a user profile, you have a route defined for that let's say `user/profile`. From this route I don't know the user I'm trying to view the profile, but I also know the user must be logged in to view his profile. I would write a plug to check if he is having a session and set in my assigns map `current_user`. Phoenix, will call the concerned controller with the according action let's say it's `show_profile(conn, _params)`, and conn will have everything set and I can then send the required template or response to the user.